# iOS 13 App Store update missing from the Account panel

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

I transferred my wife's data to my prior iPhone SE (2016) today. The old iPhone was running iOS 12 and the new phone is updated to run iOS 13.5.

Everything seems to be working so far except for the App Store. When you go into the App Store and tap on the account icon at the top, it shows the account panel with her name logged in, "Purchased", "Redeem Gift Card or Code", "Send Gift Card by Email", "Add Funds to Apple ID", "Personalized Recommendations", and "Sign Out".

It should be showing a list of applications to update between "Personalized Recommendations" and "Sign Out", right? Or do these sections not show at all in the new location in iOS 13 if all of the apps were already updated prior to the phone change and in the old location in iOS 12?

(And if so, that's dumb that Apple can't apply the data from the old place to the new place!) I just want to make sure it transferred correctly before her old phone is repurposed for something else. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: First make sure there are any pending updates. You can do that by going to installed apps page on the App Store and checking if there is an update available.

Comment: Everything was already updated before the move.  The old phone shows the updates.  The question is if there are no updates pending, would that whole section be missing?  And why would I not see the updates done on the old phone?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the update section doesn't appear in the account list at all until an update is available or has been automatically applied.  Any updates applied on the prior phone with the older iOS don't show in the list.

I had hoped to figure all this out right away when I was doing the phone change so I would know that the phone transfer had worked successfully.  (I initially feared that the transfer had partially failed and that I wouldn't be able to do updates on the new phone.)  But I ended up needing to wait for an app to need an upgrade to get my answer for sure.  So hopefully this question and answer will help somebody else who is going through that to know that the transfer worked out fine and not to worry about that.